# Excel solution required to calculate the sum of cells according to reference cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I want to calculate the overburden pressure at certain depth (reference C14) but including the effect of water table. As, below water table submerged density should be considered and above saturated density should be considered. So, i am looking for a formula which can calculate automatically the pressure by changing the water table depth (reference E1). Please see the attachments (spreadsheet and images):

[image: Sample image]

[image: sample image with cell formulas]

[Sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t323yrpbrx79oil/water%20table.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: `Please see attachments` ... please don't include links to outside images.  Your question should try to include all relevant data, as text, directly in the question.

Comment: Actually to give better picture of the problem i did. Only spreadsheet is outside link.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an Engineering question.

Comment: It's not a engineering question, if you unable to solve then let someone else. It's VBA code or formula in excel.

Comment: Could you explain the calculation needed - _I want to calculate the overburden pressure at certain depth_ is an Engineering question, explaining the calculation and asking how to translate to Excel is an Excel question.

Comment: Basically i tried with "SUBTOTAL" function, but it is not working due to the incorrect arguments. i use this for Pile capacity Calculations. So, if any solution you have it will save numerous time.

Answer (score 0):

Dont know exactly if i understand what you are trying.

You can use nested if clause to get what you want to do:

```
=IF(E5<3;"DOE SOMETHING HERE for EGL 0-3";IF(E5<7,5;"DO SOMETHING HERE FOR 3-7.5";"DO SOMETHING FOREGL ABOVE 7.5"))
```

I just did 3 Steps but it should be clear from here. Excel will evalualte the if clause from left to right until it reaches the first thing that matches. This whay you can just always ask "E5 < Max Value" because if it is between 3 and 7.5 the first if will not trigger but the second one and the it ends. For the last step you just use the "Else" clause.

Comment: Actually in some cases there will be more than 8 layers. So again everytime have to edit that lf condition. I am using this now. Any better solutions ?

Comment: It is the best thing i can do without knowing the exact calculation you try to do. Like what happens with "Above Watertable" And "Below Watertable" Do you add them? How you arrive at 19,2 when you put in 9,5?  

I cant download the excel file that would maybe clarifie that. So maybe go into a little bit of detail. When i remeber it i will download it at home.